# Prompt option is not working in Edit view in Active Admin in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have two select boxes.

In one select box in edit mode, prompt is showing that 'select certification provider'.
But in another select box in edit mode, prompt is not showing that 'select certification'.

```
f.input :certificate_provider ,as: :select ,:collection => CertificateProvider.select('id,name').map{|c| [c.name,c.id]} , :prompt => "Select Certification Provider"
f.input :certification ,as: :select ,:collection => Certification.select('id,name').map{|c| [c.name,c.id]} , :prompt => "Select Certification"
```

I don't know why it is showing prompt in one select box and but not in second one in edit mode.

Is there anything left to do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use :include_blank instead of :prompt

```
:include_blank => "Select Certification"
```

modify your code as:

```
f.input :certification ,as: :select ,:collection => Certification.select('id,name').map{|c| [c.name,c.id]} , :include_blank => "Select Certification"
```

this will work in both new and edit.

Comment: Thank you. Yesterday i have already find out one solution but your suggestion is better then me. So thank you@mani